# creating a token using ERC20 and using it for gas in private blockchain?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, erc-20

is it possible to create a token using the ERC20 and using it instead of ether in a private blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

**in short** : it is not possible as ether is the underlying currency used to pay miners for the transaction fees(e.g you could not send a transaction if you don't have enough ethers to cover the fees) and used as a reward for the mining reward . These rules are defined in the ethereum protocol to change them you have to rebuild the whole system. But as you are in a private chain ether itself could be considered as a token.

Answer (score 0):

There is [ERC865 Pay transfers in tokens instead of gas](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865).